# Angular 8 with Ivy enabled - @swimlane/ngx-datatable throwing entry-point error

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable, angular8

@swimlane/ngx-datatable throwing error when Ivy renderer got enabled with Angular 8.

Updated the @swimlane/ngx-datatable package with 15.0.0 and also tried with some patch 'git+https://github.com/zackarychapple/ngx-datatable.git'

package.json

Option 1:

```
"dependencies": {
....

"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "git+https://github.com/zackarychapple/ngx-datatable.git",

...

}
```

Option 2:

```
"dependencies": {
....

"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "15.0.0",

...

}
```

> ERROR in There is no format with import statements in '/Users/omnimac/work/engage3/mywld-shopper-webapp.cip-v2/lighthouse/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable' entry-point.

Comment: Ivy is experimental, most libs aren't ready. Just wait until v9, using Ivy wouldn't change anything right now as the tooling is not ready to care advantage of it yet anyway

Comment: Creator of ngx-datatable Marjan Georgiev (@marjan-Georgiev)  has replied here. https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1699#issuecomment-498247654